# Windows Phone Preserving Page State not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am trying to preserve the page state when i go to another page, but for some reason when i go back to this page, the items are returned to their default state. Why doesn't it work? It seems to follow the tutorials perfectly...

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);


        State["Title"] = TitleTextBox.Text;

        //all of those are RadioButtons - if their is a better way to do it then please comment :)
        int i = new int();
        if (RB0.IsChecked.Value)
            i = 0;
        else if (RB1.IsChecked.Value)
            i = 1;
        else if (RB2.IsChecked.Value)
            i = 2;
        else if (RB3.IsChecked.Value)
            i = 3;
        State["CheckedRB"] = i;

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (State.ContainsKey("Title"))
            TitleTextBox.Text = State["Title"] as string;
        if (State.ContainsKey("CheckedRB"))
        {
            int i = (int)State["CheckedRB"];

            if (i == 0)
                RB0.IsChecked = true;
            else if (i == 1)
                RB1.IsChecked = true;
            else if (i == 2)
                RB2.IsChecked = true;
            else if (i == 3)
                RB3.IsChecked = true;
        }
     }
```

**Edit:** I traced the problem by adding breakpoints.

```
            protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);


        State["Title"] = TitleTextBox.Text;
        string look0 = WorkOutName.Text; 
        string look = State["WorkOutName"] as string; 

        int i = new int();
        if (RB0.IsChecked.Value)
            i = 0;
        else if (RB1.IsChecked.Value)
            i = 1;
        else if (RB2.IsChecked.Value)
            i = 2;
        else if (RB3.IsChecked.Value)
            i = 3;
        State["CheckedRB"] = i;   <-------- breakpoint
```

and here are the results:

```
(OnNavigatedFrom)
look0 : "Text From TextBox"
look1 : "Text From TextBox"
i : (0, 1, 2, or 3)
```

and same with OnNavigatedTo:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (State.ContainsKey("Title"))
            TitleTextBox.Text = State["Title"] as string; <--breakpoint
        if (State.ContainsKey("CheckedRB"))
        {
            int i = (int)State["CheckedRB"]; <--breakpoint

            if (i == 0)
                RB0.IsChecked = true;
            else if (i == 1)
                RB1.IsChecked = true;
            else if (i == 2)
                RB2.IsChecked = true;
            else if (i == 3)
                RB3.IsChecked = true;
        }
     }
```

**and Neither one of them (on OnNavigatedTo) go off.**

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it seems to work fine. I don't know if this is your case, but remember that if you have the following navigation flow in the app:

```
Page1 (forward navigation)-> Page2 (back navigation)-> Page1 (forward navigation)-> Page2
```

If you saved the state in Page2 when first visiting it, that state will NOT be preserved when returning to Page2 again, this is because when doing a back navigation the page is discarded and so is the state dictionary for that page. You can read more about that in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967548%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).